# making table with two dimensional list in python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, syntax

I need to create a table that has two columns and essentially 12 rows.

the range of column 1 needs to be (-10,110,10)

the range of column 2 would be a number based off of a mathematical expression done to the numbers in column one.

the first one I need to build deals with temperatures.
I need it to look like this when I print it out.

Fahrenheit ------------------ Celsius

-10------------------------------35

0--------------------------------65

10-------------------------------25

20-------------------------------65

the Celsius column number will use the mathematical conversion to convert the Fahrenheit number to Celsius. Or I could build the list by hand.

the problem I am having is I don't understand how to accomplish this.

I don't really understand what's going on when creating a two dimensional list as well as how to format it to look like ^^said list^^ or something close.

I have read and read the text were covering but it doesn't state anything about doing something like this. looking for the proper syntax and an explanation of what's going on with in that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a table for something this simple.  You can use a list of tuples to accomplish the same thing.

```
def f2c(f_temp):
    return (f_temp - 32) * 5 / 9

f_temps = range(-10, 110, 10)
c_temps = [f2c(t) for t in f_temps]

combined = zip(f_temps, c_temps)

for f_temp, c_temp in combined:
    print('{0}...{1}'.format(f_temp, c_temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

A matrix like structure can be created using print method of python 3.x. For python 2.7 or above we have to add an import statement like `from __future__ import print_function`

```
def fahren2Celsius(f):
    c = (f - 32) / 1.8000
    return c

print("Fahrenheit", "Celsius", sep = "\t\t")

for x in range(-10,110,10):
    print("{}".format(x),"{}".format( fahren2Celsius(x) ), sep="\t\t\t")
```

I hope this is what you are looking for